# How to know the share status of my website posts on social media?

Tags: social-media, social-sharing-buttons

I installed a social media sharing button WordPress plugin on my website. Now, there is a list of sharing buttons underneath each post. I want to know how to check if somebody shares my posts on social media such as Facebook and Twitter.